# Php- Check string is either a decimal or fractions

Tags: php, mysql

I have an input box that users can type in their odds for a bet. This can either be in the form of a decimal so -> 1 or 6.2 ect or a fraction e.g 5/1 or 13/2 ect

what would be the best way to check these are input?

Comment: Your specs are kind of vague. Is `.6` valid? And `-13/2`? And `6.2/33`? Do you accept spaces, as in `13 / 2`?

Comment: ok so .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 . .7 .8 .9 are all valied
no - wont be accepted just whole fractions no "+" or "-" i trim the value to remove any spaces

Comment: See my answer below, it does exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think regex is the best way to do this

```
if(preg_match("@^\d*\.?\d+(/\d*\.?\d+)?$@", $value)) {
   echo "$value is valid";
}
```

this regex allow : .1 | 2.0/54 | 2.3 | .5/.8 | 8/7 | 85.98 | .....
if you need also the `,` character (for some language use it) then  `"@^\d*[\.,]?\d+(/\d*[\.,]?\d+)?$@""`

EDIT Fixed "4/" case

Comment: I really want to know why the downvote ? what is incorrect in my answer ? ... let me know

Comment: I have taken the above and added a filter so but . and / cannot be used together

if(preg_match("@^\d*\.?\d+(/\d*\.?\d+)?$@", $value)) {
if (strpos($value, '.')!==false and strpos($value, '/')!== false) {
 

    if (strpos($_POST["Odds"][$i], '/') !== false)
     {
     $Odds = round(fraction(test_input($_POST["Odds"][$i])) , 2);
     }
      else
     {
     $Odds = test_input($_POST["Odds"][$i]);
     }
   }
     else{
      $errorMessage.= "<li>Odds can only be fractions OR decimal!</li>";
      
     }

}

Answer (score -1):

Use a regular expression such as `^(\d+\/\d+|\d+\.\d+|\d+)`. It matches 1, 6.2, 5/1 and 13/2, but not .1, 1. and so on. Use the preg_match() function to check if the input matches.

```
$nums = ['1', '6.2', '5/1', '13/2', '.3', 'a'];

foreach ($nums as $num) {
   print "$num:" . preg_match("/^(\d+\/\d+|\d+\.\d+|\d+)/", $num) . "\n";
}
```